# Why don't I see my own moderator messages in the moderator inbox?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, global-inbox, top-bar

The new moderator inbox shows mod messages sent by all of our site's moderators... except myself.

On looking at the list today, it seemed that several messages were missing. I know that mod messages were sent after November 22, since I sent several of them (being almost the only mod around during the holidays).

[image]

And indeed, on manually checking, I found that *all* the messages I thought were missing were those I sent.

Is it intentional that I don't see mod messages I sent, and is there a better way for me to go find my own mod messages again if necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since these messages are your own, we opted to filter them out of notifications.

No sense in lighting up an icon to show you something you *know* already happened since you were the one who did it in the first place. :)

Note that if someone *replies* to a message you sent, that will also be excluded from the moderator notifications list: instead, it'll appear in your inbox.

If you have a pressing need to view *all* moderator messages, regardless of author or intended recipient, you can find them under [/admin/users](https://serverfault.com/admin/users).

Comment: I could see the argument for showing them all if people want that.

Comment: What about adding it to the list but not lighting it up unless it was already lit up by something else?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I guess if you sent a bunch of messages, you could push every "new and potentially useful" notification down/out of the list? Not sure if that's a real concern.

Comment: MAybe it's a concern on SO, but I doubt any other site has enough mod messages to worry about that.

Comment: How big is the chance of not having read notifications before messaging users though?

Comment: @ThiefMaster No idea. I can see it happening, though. Checking notification isn't a prerequisite for doing anything else.

Comment: Now that I have sent a moderator message (doesn't happen often), I find it confusing as hell that messages from other moderators are in the moderator inbox, replies to my own mod messages are in my regular inbox (why are they not in my moderator inbox?), and messages I've sent are less accessible than messages sent by others. My own messages should be in my mod inbox, of course marked as read automatically.