# Replies to mod messages go to normal inbox rather than mod inbox?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, moderator-tools, global-inbox

As a moderator on [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com), I mod messaged a user about a moderation issue.

Weird thing is, when the user replied, I got it in my normal inbox, rather than my mod inbox.

Attached is a screenshot (personal details obviously hidden and freehand circles added):

[image: Screenshot]

Another moderator saw it in his mod inbox as normally.

Is this a bug? Or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: That was probably just a logistical decision (do you even get notifications of things in the mod box?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I get notifications mainly for meta questions asked on my site, and I do remember getting mod message notifications there.

Comment: OK.  Maybe that's something they did on SO to remove noise, but I don't get notified of anything in that diamond in box.  There are several mod messages there from four hours ago, and I didn't get notified of any of them.  I do, however, get notified when someone replies to one of my mod messages.

Comment: Yeah, messaging on Stack Overflow has behaved this way for a good long while now, @Robert. We didn't extend this behavior to other sites until just before the new top-bar was rolled out (with the separate notifications queue going away, it made sense to make this behavior consistent everywhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, moderator messages are considered *informational* - something that you (as a moderator on a given site) should be *aware of* and perhaps review when you have the time, but not something you need to read immediately and almost certainly not something you should reply to.

But if you send someone a message and they reply, that's specifically directed *at you* - and as such, it goes into your inbox, just as replies to posts you've written or comments you've left would. Even if you're currently using a different site, it's important that you're at least *aware* that someone you sent a Big Scary Message has responded; whether or not any further action is needed will depend on the nature of the reply.

#### Related: [Why don't I see my own moderator messages in the moderator inbox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210057/why-dont-i-see-my-own-moderator-messages-in-the-moderator-inbox)